# Can I get the original PDF files with Solr in the UI after indexing?

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to build a enterprise search engine with solr. I am indexing some PDFs and doc files to Solr. I am creating UI with SolrJ. Can I get the original PDF files with Solr in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Solr` won't store the files at its end, So there is no scope of getting the original PDF file from solr.

But you can store the path of the file and can provide a link in the user interface for file to be downloaded.

You can use the path given by `solr` and get the file from that location.

Comment: Can u please explain how can I give links to documents? I am using path given by solr.

Comment: @Yashu : are you getting the path of pdf where there are stored? If yes use if as relative path and when you perform any action like download ...use that path and download the document...

Comment: Yes I have path of PDFs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052825/how-to-give-links-to-many-pdfs/37087586#37087586   Here is my output. Now I just want to give link to the paths. So when I will click on  "file:Y:/ACS...." It should redirect to the corresponding PDF.

Comment: then you have to use the path for the actions you want to perform..like download , view etc..